# is it true to use normrand for Gaussian distribution in matlab

Tags: matlab, linear-regression

I wanna code simple linear regression in Matlab and I wrote this code. it's work but I don't feel right about it!! I imagine something goes wrong. if you mind take a look on it;

---

```
clc,clear

h1 = normrnd(1:10,1);
P_re = normrnd(1:10,1);

n = numel(h1);

y = h1.*P_re;
y1 = sum(y);

sumH = sum(h1);
sumP = sum(P_re);

sumh_2 = sum((h1).^2);
sumh2 = (sum(h1))^2;

beta1 = ((n*y1) - sumH*sumP)/(n*(sumh_2)-(sumh2));
beta0 = mean(P_re) - beta1*mean(h1);

pRe = beta1*h1 + beta0;

plot(h1,P_re,'o')
hold on
plot(pRe,h1)
```

Comment: Also, the title doesn't reflect what is actually being asked

Answer (score 0):

You can get the two regression coefficients simply using [`polyfit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html) to fit a polynomial of degree 1. Also, you probably mean `plot(h1, pRe)` rather than `plot(h1, pRe)`:

```
clc,clear
h1 = normrnd(1:10,1); % x data
P_re = normrnd(1:10,1); % y data
beta = polyfit(h1, P_re, 1); % fit polynomial of order 1
pRe = beta(1)*h1 + beta(2); % or pRe = polyval(beta, h1)
plot(h1,P_re,'o') % plot data
hold on
plot(h1,pRe) % plot fitted line
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I corrected my code as you said and it's working well